# how to use logic with aggregate result

Tags: apex, aggregate

here i created one code which will retrieve record from "Account" object and create records in "abc" object based on selected fields.
  i used "AggregateResult" to add numbers with current year and that will increase record by record.

**now the issue is i want to show 5 zero leading a no.
  e.g, 2014-000001
    2014-000010 and so on...
i did the logic but its showing like  2014-01 or 2014-010...only one '0'
i am not getting what going wrong...Please help me out....**

Apex code:

```
 Integer Month = (system.today().addDays(30)).month();      
 Integer Year = system.today().year();
 Integer Day = system.today().day();


 List<Account> accList = [Select Id,StartDate__c,endDate__c,Amount__c From Account  where  CALENDAR_MONTH(endDate__c) = :currentMonth and CALENDAR_YEAR(endDate__c) < = :currentYear and DAY_IN_MONTH(endDate__c) = :Day];


 List<AggregateResult> argList = [select count(id) cnt from abc__c where Number__c like '2014%'];
 integer nextInvNum = (integer)arList[0].get('cnt');
 nextInvNum++;
 List<abc__c> abcList = new List<abc__c>();
 for(Account a : accList) {
 abc__c ab = new abc__c();
 ab.Account__c = a.Id;           
 ab.StartDate__c = a.StartDate__c;
 ab.endDate__c = a.endDate__c;
 ab.Amount__c = a.Amount__c;

 string nextInvNumStr = '';
 if(nextInvNum < 10)nextInvNumStr = '00000'+nextInvNum;
 if(nextInvNum < 100)nextInvNumStr = '0000'+nextInvNum;
 if(nextInvNum < 1000)nextInvNumStr = '000'+nextInvNum;
 if(nextInvNum < 10000)nextInvNumStr = '0'+nextInvNum;
 if(nextInvNumStr == '')nextInvNumStr = ''+nextInvNum;

 ab.Number__c = (system.today().year() +'-'+ nextInvNumStr);
 nextInvNum++;
 abcList.add(ab); 
}
insert abcList;
```

Comment: How many records do you have that match the query criteria? If it's showing only one '0' that means you have more than 1000 records returning from the query since you're initializing the `nextInvNum` variable to the record count it will start assigning from your 4th `if` statement.

Comment: Keith's answer beat me out... you need to use if ..else  :)

Answer (score 2):

If you take an example of say 5, all your `if(nextInvNum` tests are true and each one does its assignment with the last one (that only adds a single '0') winning.

One way to fix this is:

```
if(nextInvNum < 10)nextInvNumStr = '00000'+nextInvNum;
else if(nextInvNum < 100)nextInvNumStr = '0000'+nextInvNum;
else if(nextInvNum < 1000)nextInvNumStr = '000'+nextInvNum;
else if(nextInvNum < 10000)nextInvNumStr = '0'+nextInvNum;
else if(nextInvNumStr == '')nextInvNumStr = ''+nextInvNum;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use if-else conditional statement instead of simple if statements.

Comment: That's a very short answer (It got automatically reported as low quality). Could you possibly explain further or include the specific code changes as an example ?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution is to pad with zeros and then trim - too many if/else makes code difficult to read and more error prone. e.g.

```
integer nextInvNumStr=84;
string output = system.today().year() +'-'+ (('00000'+nextInvNumStr).right(6));
system.debug(output);
```

output is 2014-000084

Answer (score 0):

// I am using Aggregate result but that functionality not working properly
// i Write code like this. This working properly.
// what is the use of Aggregateresult

```
trigger aggregate_result_is_not_working on ChildAccount__c (after insert, after update, after delete) {

    list<ParentAccount__c> acc=[select id, Childs_Amount__c, (select id, Rec_Amount__c from ChildAccounts__r) from ParentAccount__c];
    list<ParentAccount__c> act=new list<ParentAccount__c>();

    for(ParentAccount__c aa:acc){
      aa.Childs_Amount__c=0;
        for(ChildAccount__c cc:aa.ChildAccounts__r){ 
        aa.Childs_Amount__c= aa.Childs_Amount__c + cc.Rec_Amount__c;

        }
        act.add(aa);
    }
    update act;
}
```